# Let a and b be relatively prime integers. Show that the numbers $0, 2a, 3a, ..., (b-1)a$ all lie in distinct congruence classes modulo b

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Let a and b be relatively prime integers. Show that the numbers $0, 2a, 3a, ..., (b-1)a$ all lie in distinct congruence classes modulo b

Here's my solution, It's a bit long, Is it correct?

1. First of all, 0 lies in the first congruence class modulo b
   No other multiplies of a less than ab can lie in the same class as 0 as a and b are coprime.
   So this is proved for 0

Let $m$ be an integer where $0 < m < b$.

Assume  $ma \cong n \mod  b$

$n$ shouldn't equal $0$, otherwise $a$ and $b$ won't be coprime
$n$ shouldn't equal $b$ as well

so $0 < n < b$

Now what?

Assume that there exists an integer $v$ where $0 < v < b$, $v$ doesn't equal m and $va \cong n \mod b$

so   $$va \cong n \mod b$$  $$ma \cong n \mod  b $$

$$va - n \cong 0 \mod b$$ $$ ma - n \cong 0 \mod  b$$

Let $e$ and $d$ be integers
$$va - n = eb $$

$$ma - n = db $$

Subtracting

$$va - ma = (e-d)b$$
$$va \cong ma \mod b$$
$$v \cong m \mod b$$

So $m$ divides $v$

Back to
$$va - n = eb $$

$$ma - n = db $$

Subtracting second equation from first we get that
$$m \cong v \mod b$$

So v divides m 
But m divides v
So m = v
Which is a contradiction as m doesn't equal v in the assumption

Q.E.D

Comment: Seems good, but long.  I think it'd be simpler and shorter to prove $na \equiv ma \mod b; 0\le m < b; 0 \le n < b \implies n = m$.  Then 0a, .... (b-1)a must belong to distinct cogruency classes.

Comment: ...$na \equiv ma \mod b \implies na - ma = (n-m)a = kb \implies n-m = (kb)/a$ an integer.  As a and b are coprime $n-m = (k/a)b$ and $k/a$ is an integer.  So $n \equiv m \mod b$.  If $0 \le n,m < b$ then $n = m$.  So if $n,m$ are distinct numbers between 0 and b-1 then $na$ and $ma$ are in distinct congruency classe.  Fits in a comment with 233 characters to spare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct. From $v\equiv m\pmod b$, you don't get that $m$ divides $v$, but rather that $b$ divides $v-m$. Can you obtain a contradiction from here?

(Also, $m\equiv v\pmod b$ and $v\equiv m\pmod b$ are saying the same thing, so you don't need to do this twice.)

Comment: Found the contradiction and completed the proof, thanks! (by the way shouldn't m = dv implies that m divides v I'm very confused)

Comment: From what you wrote, you have $v\equiv m\pmod b$ (and not $m=dv$), no?

Comment: oh yeah woops, I meant that shouldn't $v \cong m  \mod b$ imply that m divides v (or v divides m) iirc?

Comment: No, the meaning of $v\equiv m\pmod b$ is that $b$ divides $v-m$. :)

Comment: See here for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: well I thought it meant both, but that clarifies things, thanks